# Stylus - set url() prefix for cli compiles

Tags: stylus

I'm using Stylus CSS preprocessor, console compiler not javascript middleware. I'm looking for some kind of path prefix configuration.

So when I write (in **foo.styl**):

```
#lolipop
  background: url(images/lolipop.png)
```

and set prefix `static/`, I want it to compile into:

```
#lolipop {
    background: url("static/images/lolipop.png");
}
```

Is this possible with stylus's console compiler only?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Since you use the stylus executable, here is your solution. It seems totally undocumented, but you can actually `--use url` and pass along the options as a string, like this:

```
stylus --use url --with "{ paths: [ './static' ] }"
```

This feature works similar to `url` from the [stylus url() documentation](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/functions.url.html) and takes the same options:

> For example if our images live in ./public/images and we wish to use url(images/tobi.png), we can pass paths with our public directory, which will become part of the lookup process. Like-wise if we wanted url(tobi.png) instead, we would pass paths: [__dirname + '/public/images'].

```
stylus(str)
  .set('filename', __dirname + '/css/test.styl')
  .define('url', stylus.url({ paths: [__dirname + '/public'] }))
  .render(function(err, css){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 prefix = 'static/'

#lolipop
  background: url(prefix + images/lolipop.png)
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but this works.

Comment: I don't like this solution very much. In SASS there is a config file sass.config.rb which is read by cli compiler. You are able to setup url/filesystem prefixes for url(), @font-face etc. It is very convenient way how to customize output of the compiler. Well, I'm thinking in filling feature rq in issue tracker. Thanks for answer anyway.